# How can I access my USB drive from 2nd router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, usb

I have a router connected to internet and a USB drive attached to it with movies.

I also have a 2nd router outside my home attached by UTP directly to the 1st router.

I want to connect to my 2nd router by WiFi (using my iPad) and stream the movies (using VLC app) from the 1st router through the 2nd router and then watching it on my iPad, how can this be achieved?

Comment: What app are you using on the ipad to try to access the files?

Answer (score -1):

You might have a double NAT situation (example: different subnets on each router) preventing the connection. Consider using your 2nd router in Access point mode only and that should resolve the issue.

Comment: You should provide detaiiled steps on how to do that.

Comment: The question is too broad to be able to provide that level of detail. The configuration changes will be different for every router. The endgame here is, get everything on one subnet and continue troubleshooting from there.

Comment: already fixed, both router were on same subnet but I forgot to add username and password to the connect option in VLC, better UI needed 